# How do I protect a web service that does not require authentication from phony consumers?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am writing asp.net generic web handlers to provide service to a web application, but I don't want a phony application to use the web handlers. The purpose of using the web handlers is to conceal logic and data. But even though the logic and data is protected, someone can still use the handlers from outside the web application because it does not require authentication. How do I resolve this?

Edit: The proper client is a JavaScript application using ajax.

Comment: In attempting to answer this question, all ideas point towards just adding authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You first have to define "phony application".

If you are unable/unwilling to add authentication, you can consider physically isolating the service so that only legitimate applications can use it.

One solid method is to place the web service behind a firewall and configure access only for applications that should be able to reach it.

Answer (score 0):

If the list of applications you need to have access to the application is small and/or local, you could encrypt the data returned (and data taken as parameters?) with some symmetric algorithm, and disclose the key to the other applications' developers.  You could also generate a new key per application to hide data between apps using your service, but at this point you may as well just use normal authentication methods.

Comment: But you cannot do that with a java script client, can you, because the encryption key and algorithm would be exposed.

Comment: @GuidoArbia You should really provide more information in the OP.  Anyway, I'm not very experienced with web development but couldn't you use Ajax to make a request to the server without postback, assuming the goal is to avoid postback.  If that's acceptable, then the server ought to be able to decrypt the data before returning it to the user page.